# logstash re-read input file everytime there is modification

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I have an input file named test.csv and I use it as some kind of configuration. How do i force logstash to re read the file from beginning, everytime there is modification in the test.csv file

Edit:
my logstash config

input {

```
file {

  type => "csv_conf"

  path => ["/opt/test.csv"]

  start_position => "beginning"

  sincedb_path => "/dev/null"

}
```

}

filter {

```
if ([type] == "csv_conf") {

  csv {

     columns => ["ip1", "ip2", "desc"]

  }

}
```

}

output {

```
stdout {

  codec => rubydebug

}
```

}

Comment: can you update your question with your logstash config?

Comment: edited post with my config

Comment: This would work if you restart logstash on each change or you could use the output exec command to copy the file (new file -> new parse).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I do not want to restart the logstash
Can you tell me how I can use output exec command?

Comment: new file doesn't necessarily take a new inode, so it doesnt work always

Comment: yeah, i just tried it and the main issue for me is that it ends in an infinite loop. Because the input is triggered on each output regardless of whether there is new input (because the copied file is found as a new file) - can you elaborate on your usecase? There might be an alternative solution to your problem